# How to Display the data from mysql to datagridview with default column name display already using vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

This is my datagridview [Screenshot of Datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03x2q.gif)I need help. How to display the data of mysql database to my datagridview which has default header text or Column name that I set already. Im using search button.I use this code it queries from different table and my default column names does not place the data. Anyone, could suggest me the correct code to display my data

```
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = ("server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;password=12345;database=dbsis3bkenth;")
        Try
            conn.Open()
            For k As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
                sql = "SELECT (LName,FName,MI) FROM tblsisterbrother where IDNoBrodSis = '" & cbIDNo.Text & "'" & _
                    "VALUES ('" & DataGridView1.Rows(k).Cells("LN").Value.ToString & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(k).Cells("FN").Value.ToString & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(k).Cells("MI").Value.ToString & "');"
                cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
                dr.Read()
            Next

        If dr.HasRows = True Then
            MessageBox.Show("Record Found.!")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Record Unfound.!")
        End If
        dr.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Error in searching to database:error is:" & ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    dr.Close()
    Dim DataAdapter1 As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter
    DataAdapter1.SelectCommand = cmd
    DataAdapter1.Fill(ds, "tblsisterbrother")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "tblsisterbrother"
    conn.Close()
```

Comment: Your query is wrong and many other things. Your performing a select but have values, doesn't make sense. There is SQL injection possibility, objects not being disposed of, and many others...

Comment: Hahaha.. Im only a newbie student. could you help me to make it right sir? much appreciate. Thanks :)

Comment: That root password looks like the combination to my luggage.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn I would assume that's not a safe one ;)

Comment: If what you are asking is for your (garish) columns not to be replaced, use `DatagridView1.AutogenerateColumns = False`..but there is lots else wrong that many many many posts here explain.  look for SQL Parameters

Comment: Ohh.. Ok2 sir Plutonix :) I mean the column header must be stay and the data that i query from my database will place according to the column Header.